# How to set ImageView and TextView in OnPostMethod of AsyncClass

Tags: android-layout, android-asynctask, android

I want to set image and text in imageview and textview in the OnPostMethod of AsyncClass, like I am doing some network operations in "do in background" method, and on a particular response I just want to populate imageviews and textviews with particular images and texts.

Can someone tell me how to set image in OnPostMethod. I wonder if someone can tell me the mistake I am making in the following code

```
 public class testing_async extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String s;
    ImageView im;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing_async);
        new GetCategoryList().execute(s);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);

    }

    //
    // THE AsyncTask Class for GetCategoryList....
    //
    class GetCategoryList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(testing_async.this, "",
                    "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

            /*
             * LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(testing_async.this);
             * layout = new LinearLayout(testing_async.this);
             * layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
             * ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             * ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
             * 
             * RelativeLayout inner_layout = new
             * RelativeLayout(testing_async.this); inner_layout = new
             * RelativeLayout(testing_async.this); layout.setLayoutParams(new
             * ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             * ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
             * 
             * ImageView im = new ImageView(testing_async.this);
             * im.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_background);
             * RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams90 = new
             * RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 225, 250); layoutParams90.leftMargin
             * = 45; layoutParams90.topMargin = 45;
             * im.setLayoutParams(layoutParams90); inner_layout.addView(im);
             * layout.addView(inner_layout);
             */
            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: your code looks good... may there is not a problem...

Comment: I dont really know when a background appear in a ImageView so i would suggest trying with `im.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Context mContext;
ImageView im;

public GetCategoryList(Context context, ImageView myIm) {

 this.mContext = context;
 this.im = myIml;

}
```

Add the custom constructor above to your async task. This way you have a context and a reference to your imageView. It will be needed in order to get the resource.

Second, all the commented code should be placed inside "onCreate".

Finally, you can assign a drawable to your imageView using

```
im.setBackgroundResource(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bBack));
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. NEVER change layout in "doInBackground". Your app will crash.

Answer (score -2):

if you are setting image

then you have to give `im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bBack);`

you are setting id not image in your code.